# Specific constraint in Or-tools is too slow, are there other methods?

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I have a problem and using ortools is too slow.

The problem is that there is an item that stores have but at different prices. I need to select where to pick those items from to achieve the lowest total price as well as not exceeding 4 stores.

This is the code I have but it is slow if the supplied cost matrix has more than 4 stores. The problem lies in the store max limit constraint. Is there any other way that this can be coded differently to improve speed?

```py
import numpy as np
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

#cost matrix, where j are stores, i are items

C = np.array([[38, 13, 73, 10, 76,  6, 80, 65, 17,  2],
        [77, 72,  7, 26, 51, 21, 19, 85, 12, 29],
        [30, 15, 51, 69, 88, 88, 95, 97, 87, 14],
        [10,  8, 64, 62, 23, 58,  2,  1, 61, 82],
        [ 9, 89, 14, 48, 73, 31, 72,  4, 71, 22],
        [50, 58,  4, 69, 25, 44, 77, 27, 53, 81],
        [42, 83, 16, 65, 69, 26, 99, 88,  8, 27],
        [26, 23, 10, 68, 24, 28, 38, 58, 84, 39],
        [ 9, 33, 35, 11, 24, 16, 88, 26, 72, 93],
        [75, 63, 47, 33, 89, 24, 56, 66, 78,  4],
        [ 1, 78,  7, 53, 86, 71,  3, 77, 92, 22],
        [76,  8, 78, 73, 76, 77, 44, 21, 31, 37],
        [ 8, 46, 69, 58, 83, 97, 14, 11, 24, 82],
        [ 8, 25, 75, 93, 21, 33, 13, 66, 95, 61],
        [25, 83, 98,  3, 93, 99, 11, 55, 97, 83],
        [87, 71, 67, 72, 49, 55, 16,  6, 18, 43],
        [21, 49, 23, 14, 98, 54, 85, 11, 97, 56],
        [62, 57, 90, 22, 97, 84, 26, 15, 14, 85],
        [44,  7, 78, 57, 60, 16, 25, 10, 67, 72],
        [54, 70, 37, 22, 41, 78, 92, 50, 48, 78]])
    
    # The solver:
def Solve_Cost_Matrix_2(cost):
    model = cp_model.CpModel()
    max_stops = 4

    #generate ranges
    num_items = len(cost)
    num_shops = len(cost[0])
    
    all_items = range(num_items)
    all_shops = range(num_shops)
    

    # Create bool Variable matrix
    x = []
    for i in all_items:
        t=[]
        for j in all_shops:
            t.append(model.NewBoolVar(f'i{i}_j{j}'))
        x.append(t)
    
        # Constraints
        # Each item only assigned once to any store.
    [model.Add(sum(x[i][j] for j in all_shops) == 1) for i in all_items]
           
        
    # Adding the intermediate variable to constrain the number of the stores. 
    s=[]
    for j in all_shops:
        s.append( model.NewBoolVar(f's_{j}') )
          
    for j in all_shops:
        model.Add(sum(x[i][j] for i in all_items) >= 1).OnlyEnforceIf(s[j])
        model.Add(sum(x[i][j] for i in all_items) == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(s[j].Not())
    
    model.Add(sum(s[j] for j in all_shops) <= max_stops)
  
        
    # Create the Objective function Variable
    total_cost = model.NewIntVar(0, 1000000, 'total_cost')


    # Create the Objective function, Minimize (Sum of cost) 
    model.Add(total_cost == (sum(x[i][j] * cost[i][j] for j in all_shops for i in all_items )))

    model.Minimize(total_cost)
    
        
    #Initialize the Solver
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    status = solver.Solve(model)
    
    print(solver.ResponseStats())
    Total_Cost,senario_cost = 0, 0
      
  
    #printing the solution
    if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
        senario_cost={'Items':[],'Assigned_to':[],'Item_cost':[],'Num_stops':0,'cost':[]}
        Total_Cost = solver.ObjectiveValue()
            
        for i in range(num_items):
            for j in range(num_shops):
                if solver.Value(x[i][j]) == 1:
                    senario_cost['Items'].append(i)
                    senario_cost['Assigned_to'].append(j)
                    senario_cost['Item_cost'].append(cost[i][j])
        senario_cost['Num_stops'] = len(set(senario_cost['Assigned_to']))
        senario_cost['cost'] = cost
        
        return Total_Cost,senario_cost
    else: return None, None
```

Output:

```
CpSolverResponse:
status: OPTIMAL
objective: 213
best_bound: 213
booleans: 210
conflicts: 106343
branches: 158796
propagations: 4242079
integer_propagations: 7844526
restarts: 878
lp_iterations: 0
walltime: 6.90529
usertime: 6.90529
deterministic_time: 4.67974
primal_integral: 0

CPU times: user 6.86 s, sys: 41 ms, total: 6.9 s
Wall time: 6.95 s
```

Comment: Can you try with solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8?

Comment: @Stradivari wow, that made it so fast. Thank you for the suggestion. If you wish to put it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

When I run the supplied code on the master branch, without parallelism, I get:

```
CpSolverResponse:
status: OPTIMAL
objective: 213
best_bound: 213
booleans: 210
conflicts: 31
branches: 617
propagations: 5226
integer_propagations: 8220
restarts: 428
lp_iterations: 130
walltime: 0.021303
usertime: 0.021303
deterministic_time: 0.0011162
primal_integral: 0.00536794
```

Do you get a different result?

Comment: I added this information on the question. I run this currently on jupyter. could that be the reason?